# Intersection of an object's value types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript `interface` that defines the HTTP methods and query parameter types I can use on a REST endpoint (see [crosswalk](https://github.com/danvk/crosswalk) for details on why you might want to do this):

```
interface API {
  '/endpoint': {
    get: {a?: string, b?: string};
    post: {b?: string, c?: string};
  } 
}
```

I want to define a function that takes this API type, the endpoint (`'/endpoint'`) and, optionally, the HTTP verb (`'get'`, `'post'`, etc.) and appropriate query parameters:

```
const urlMaker = apiUrlMaker<API>();
urlMaker('/endpoint')({a: 'a', b: 'b'});  // should be an error, we don't know that "a" is OK.
urlMaker('/endpoint')({b: 'b'});  // fine, "b" is always safe. Should return "/endpoint?b=b".
urlMaker('/endpoint', 'get')({a: 'a', b: 'b'});
// fine, we're explicitly using get. Should return "/endpoint?a=a&b=b".
```

In the case the user omits the HTTP verb, I want to accept the intersection of the query parameter types for this method (i.e. the query parameter types that can be passed to any verb).

I can get the *union* of the types this way:

```
type ParamUnion = API['/endpoint'][keyof API['/endpoint']];
// type is {a?: string, b?: string} | {b?: string, c?: string}
```

I'm aware of the trick for [converting unions to intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type), but I'm wondering if there's a way to do that in this case that doesn't go through the union. There could, of course, be any number of HTTP verbs defined for an endpoint in addition to `get` and `post` (`delete`, `put`, `patch`, etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the same basic technique, since as far as I know, [conditional type inference with `infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) is the only feature in TS which will automatically generate an intersection of an arbitrary number of types (without resorting to recursion).  You don't have to *explicitly* go through a union first, although it is still implicitly in there:

```
type ParamIntersection = {
  [K in keyof API['/endpoint']]: (x: API['/endpoint'][K]) => void
}[keyof API['/endpoint']] extends
  (x: infer I) => void ? I : never;

/* type ParamIntersection = {
    a?: string | undefined;
    b?: string | undefined;
} & {
    b?: string | undefined;
    c?: string | undefined;
} */
```

I'm turning each property type into the argument to a function and then getting the union of such functions, and inferring a single argument from this, which turns the union into an intersection via the magic of contravariance of function arguments.

This type is a bit ugly and would get worse with more intersection constitutents, so you could also merge them into a single object type:

```
type ParamMerged = {
  [K in keyof API['/endpoint']]: (x: API['/endpoint'][K]) => void
}[keyof API['/endpoint']] extends
  (x: infer I) => void ? { [K in keyof I]: I[K] } : never;

/* type ParamIntersection = {
    a?: string | undefined;
    b?: string | undefined;
    c?: string | undefined;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAUCSyDeAoZZAcgHoIQATABwHtQwiAuXAw5AcwjGZ2TgH5mAZzBRQ7ADTIARoOQixIdsgC+AblaFaInjLkLxUhPtHjVGwirxWwATyop0cKHAC2mcNCEQEYYDRBkAF4WQgBtAGlkUGQAawhbGhg0LDDScmo6cCIAXRzmAAoAD2YMTDSySlp6XMicgEpggD5kADc6Cmsw+MTksoqM6uy85AgiyEohVmLmUBhoZExGoJb24ApkfkXkZhAIVugNPBIAKmQ7B2QnF3dPKG9ff0CQ-DY+E0VlAB9kAFdKCAwUAQCgWNiyYSmJTIH7-CiA4Gg6zIABkoXBHzMsIBQL2SLexkhnxhfxxiI0KmQJxIeFpF0czjcAFloJwNi9WJFooEekkUuV0lUsgw8oUSvyBkKajk6stVh0ury+qlBZlpTlRuMMlNCDNufMoIs5W0OptcMguTElYt8os6qodsg9gcoEdTud7Aybh5IPcfH4AsF0YQBESsaT4biQWDCBD5FDvhGEXiY8hCfHidjI+TkdSgA)

Comment: You're awesome. This answer was the key to getting [joinAdapters](https://state-adapt.github.io/docs/core#joinadapters) to work in StateAdapt. I owe you big time. Seriously, do you have a "buy me coffee" link or anything like that? I spent literally an entire day on this. Never would have guessed to wrap it in a function like that.