# Object conditional key name and type remap

Tags: typescript

How to remap object key names and properties such that an existing key and property can appear as is or remaped? My current logic does not work for mixed cases:

```
export const FUNC_ENDING_HINT = "$func" as const;
type DataOrFunc<TD, K extends keyof TD> = Record<`${K}.${typeof FUNC_ENDING_HINT}`, Record<string, any[]>> | Record<K, TD[K]>;
export type DataOrFuncFromObject<TD> = DataOrFunc<TD, keyof TD>;
type Schema = {
  col1: string;
  col2: string;
};

const basic: DataOrFuncFromObject<Schema> = {
  col1: "",
  col2: ""
}
//@ts-expect-error
const incompleteBasic: DataOrFuncFromObject<Schema> = {
  col1: "",
}
//@ts-expect-error
const incompleteFunc: DataOrFuncFromObject<Schema> = {
  "col2.$func": { func: [] },
}
const funcs: DataOrFuncFromObject<Schema> = {
  "col1.$func": { func: [] },
  "col2.$func": { func: [] },
}
const mixed: DataOrFuncFromObject<Schema> = {
  col1: "",
  "col2.$func": { func: [] },
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?keyofStringsOnly=true#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-bxCyGSxGalGY1C49NCmAQNYk-KUa70ar1dn2Nq8ySaY9fVWC0G6+Gy42K+EgA)

Comment: I assume an object with both `col1` and `"col1.$func"` properties is invalid?

Comment: Ideally but not high priority. The main thing is ensuring each `Schema` property appears one way or another to ensure the mixed case is valid and to fail incomplete objects that do not specify all properties

Comment: I figured out how to avoid it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I've got it, but it's ugly and I bet it can be improved. I've used a mapped type called `DataOrFuncValuesObject` that maps the target type (`Schema` in the example) to an object type where the keys are the same but the value types are a union of objects, one in the original form (`col1: string`) and one in the function form (`"$col1.$func": Record<string, any[]>`). Then I use a type inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66445507/157247) which I've called `PropertyValueIntersection` to extract those property values as an intersection. So given:

```
type Schema = {
    col1: string;
    col2: string;
};
```

...the result is:

```
type Result =
   & ({ col1: string} | {$"col1.$func": Record<string, any[]>})
   & ({ col2: string} | {$"col2.$func": Record<string, any[]>});
```

Here it is:

```typescript
export const FUNC_ENDING_HINT = "$func" as const;

// Converts Symbol to never (see next type)
type NonSymbol<K extends PropertyKey> = K extends Symbol ? never : K;

// Converts the given object into an object where each property's type is
// a union of the key and its value type or the mapped key and the
// `Record<string, any[]>` type.
// Note: You only need the `NonSymbol` thing below if your configuration
// has `keyofStringsOnly` turned off.
type DataOrFuncValuesObject<ObjectType> = {
    [Key in keyof ObjectType]:
        | { [K in Key]: ObjectType[Key] }
        | { [K in `${NonSymbol<Key>}.${typeof FUNC_ENDING_HINT}`]: Record<string, any[]> };
};

// Extract the property types of the properties in the given object
// as an intersection; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66445507/157247
// (It's called `ParamIntersection` there and isn't generic, but that's
// where I got this from.)
type PropertyValueIntersection<O> = {
    [K in keyof O]: (x: O[K]) => void;
}[keyof O] extends (x: infer I) => void
    ? I
    : never;

// Our mapped type
type DataOrFuncFromObject<TD> = PropertyValueIntersection<DataOrFuncValuesObject<TD>>;
```

The `NonSymbol` thing in the template literal in `DataOrFuncValuesObject` feels like a hack, it seems to me I should be able exclude `symbol` from the possible types of `Key` earlier, but my attempts to do that failed.

Usage/tests:

```typescript
type Schema = {
    col1: string;
    col2: string;
};

// OK
const basic: DataOrFuncFromObject<Schema> = {
    col1: "",
    col2: "",
};
// OK
const funcs: DataOrFuncFromObject<Schema> = {
    "col1.$func": { func: [] },
    "col2.$func": { func: [] },
};
// OK
const mixed: DataOrFuncFromObject<Schema> = {
    col1: "",
    "col2.$func": { func: [] },
};
// ERROR, missing `col1` / `"col1.$func"
const wrong: DataOrFuncFromObject<Schema> = {
    "col2.$func": { func: [] },
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?keyofStringsOnly=false#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-mAD5wCNx8JJhM5tPBzMHePpXFwAC+efzMaLJfjL160I4Ec53JCCYyjeJvd+qew+GIZEoNHoOAYjehlfhSCgSJRaMxQmQOPxTekjZq8jgRBA+tWLlumySalcRPcolTbI2WzvnWAoiTL66PT61ZODUdy7CkoHsEYVQkOB7EcFoYBgMBUAqeR0FWO4ICsLhhTmYkkB0WQhFkAA2IiABZSIAVgogAGAB2WQAEYKNogAmUjaJOGxyBgPZEE+QwWU1OIhEVHRyHGNRwOVFBeUWRwd2eI5kB2eB2iiNROgQTE9B4K8lT2E4FjURxyDgdoICvI44C4RIdGJLx7QSW8Ui9L5gHE0CpJVQNw2LFtSy7ZMJWuY1KxsEAqmNeNcQ8FgsmUCBOmiQ9sW1EKGzyWJbAirsuDUOByFi5h4sS6J-NKch-KqCwrGPBRjQVOAgRBQTfm8A4HSdF03X4DBbPTf1ggYUhfKc7YtFc74PMk-1vMdGBnVdd1Js-AaRiGkaMjquAsFQIQ1NzdrfA0NZgCBbIo3zJBDAYqpN0NaQrqMFi7v1NFD2241QikaV0AFERNKqebFp6hA+ogHQ1oDE62iBXzLtja7bvYNh0X866XpRtGjxOL6fvEeBeH4JDOoW7r3XByHq2CGGzqEeH-LYJHRyJgQqhLVmqjxJs0fzJnnpZ902HZ6z3S5htG2x6QTzx374B0ToQBZIGuqW3r+up2m4Yu9GjGRthUcZjHBf4YXi1F-hxZ5qQcZPIhYVhY1YUxBXUFQfloSRwkFGhfmbpNgR8bQeA5kSQ0VbJtWwY1jMadO7XIyNgXuCFkXObjCWpaAA)

That version does allow both `col1` and `"col1.$func"` in the same object, which you [confirmed in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77854483/object-conditional-key-name-and-type-remap/77854949#comment137252522_77854483) was okay (though not ideal). But if you want to disallow that, we can do that by modifying `DataOrFuncValuesObject` to include the "other" property in each object type in the union as an optional property with the type `never`:

```typescript
// Converts the given object into an object where each property's type is
// a union of the key and its value type or the mapped key and the
// `Record<string, any[]>` type.
// Note: You only need the `NonSymbol` thing below if your configuration
// has `keyofStringsOnly` turned off.
type DataOrFuncValuesObject<ObjectType> = {
    [Key in keyof ObjectType]:
        | ({ [K in Key]: ObjectType[Key] } & {
              [K in `${NonSymbol<Key>}.${typeof FUNC_ENDING_HINT}`]?: never;
          })
        | ({ [K in `${NonSymbol<Key>}.${typeof FUNC_ENDING_HINT}`]: Record<string, any[]> } & {
              [K in Key]?: never;
          });
};
```

Then this test happily fails:

```
// ERROR, can't have both `col1` and `"col1.$func"`
const wrong2: DataOrFuncFromObject<Schema> = {
    col1: "",
    "col1.$func": { func: [] },
    "col2.$func": { func: [] },
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?keyofStringsOnly=false#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-mAD62CNx8JJhM5tPBzMHePpXFwAC+cAAZHAo-nO534y9etCOBHOdyQgmMo3iQPfqnsPhiGRKDR6DgGI3objilULFZpF3842vLu4EWbCWe0n+4OAoUR+kxxOI1PrjPCCQKNQ6IxV5X4UgoEiUWimJCMgOL4k2rbtnmh75mevQVhuZRqDu0H7tIjY1PIcBECA+qrC4tybEkaiuES7iiKmbIbFsxGdMAohJpRXQ9H01YnBqwG9hSUD2CMKoSHA9iOC0MAwGAqAVPI6CrHcEBWFwwpzMSSA6LIQiyAAbOpAAsWkAKy6QADAA7LIACMulGQATFpRknDY5AwHsiCfIYLKanEQiKjo5DjGoPHKigvKLI4wHPEcyA7PA7RRGonQIJieg8PhSp7CcCxqI45BwO0ED4UccBcIkOjEl49oJERKRel8wA+Vx-kqoG4aQTBZa9Nq1zGpWNggFUxrxriHgsFkygQJ00Rodi7Vpg2eSxLYPW9lwahwOQg3MMNo3RFBcClOQ22bpYSEyJhxoKnAQIgm5vzeAcDpOi6br8BgRXpv6wQMKQTXldsWhVd8tV+f6DWOjAzquu6f10a9IzvZ9GQYQoWCoEI0W5jdvgaGswBAtkHaxkghimVUAGGshMYE5ZxP6miaEI2moRSNK6ACiIcVVCDYOPQgz0QDo0MBpjbRAk1ePk0YRPsGw6LbRTVRsFLUjoScxoM0z8C8Pw4l3aDD3ujzfPVsEgvY0IIvbWwBOmROGsCFUJY21UeJNtL+YW0YlnW+6bB2wV7qOw2jbS0rJ2q+I8A6J0IAsuz93g09L2G8bwu4zL4tywrrsU57-De+2vv8P7zuK9ImFELCsLGrCmIR6gqD8tCluEgo0Ju4T2cCIzYfzIkhoSxzuvx7z-NG1jyeRubWfcF7PsO3GAdByXChlxXVfORF8DqqoAq5esDfi4SoWaq3VtTzn0Kd2g8BzD37SU9rnN6wnGYj0Lpsp-mlvpy7sbH+3uf237OeRdM7uz-jPQBTtA7FykEAA)

Comment: Thank you very much! All works as requested but now I need to make another change: some fields can be optional and they need to remain optional but the current logic fails at optional :(

Comment: @user5480949 - I'm afraid I can't find a way to handle that within the time I have to work on it. I had hoped it wouldn't be that big a task, but I seem to be wrong. Good luck!